# MySQLi prepared statement not binding integer

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to prepared statements. Sql query is working fine if i insert dummy data and it is working without binding the integer($id).

Where am i wrong?

```
sql = "UPDATE staff_type SET s_type=?, description=? WHERE s_type_id=?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql));      
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $type, $desc, $id);        
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Before binding parameters you have to Prepare a statement

Comment: Where is $id coming from? Have you checked it's value to make sure it is really an integer?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($stmt, $sql, $type, $desc, $id);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error which cause the integer parameter to not bind. I didn't know that disabled input fields cannot post data, therefore i found a solution to replace the 'disabled' attribute with 'readonly'.

Answer (score 1):

Before binding parameters you have to Prepare an SQL statement with parameters in it.

```
$sql = "UPDATE staff_type SET s_type=?, description=? WHERE s_type_id=?;";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);       
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $type, $desc, $id); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Please check my code, i've edited it yet not working

Comment: Well now to see the results of that query you will have to [FETCH](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) the results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Prepare Statement first

```
**Procedural style**
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE staff_type SET s_type=?, description=? WHERE s_type_id=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $type, $desc, $id); 
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql= $con->prepare("update staff_type set s_type=?, description=?  WHERE s_type_id = ?");
if ($result){
$sql->bind_param('ssi', $s_type, $desc, $s_type_id );
$sql->execute();  
}
```

side note: s represents string while i represents integer

Hope this helps you

Comment: thank you for your answer, it seems i made a silly mistake in the input field attribute